# How to create menu on admin menu bar with custom extension?

Tags: typo3

I'm new to TYPO3 and I'm building a custom extension. I want to add a menu link on admin panel like web module and list module. Please guide me step by step how to make a new module on admin side?

Comment: you might want to take a look at the documentation here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/BackendModules/BackendModuleApi/Index.html#registering-new-modules

Comment: thanks for explanation but i am new here and getting this error The default controller for extension "Transmedial" and plugin "TransmedialMysection" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php. **my code is ** \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule( 'Vendor.transmedial', 'mysection', '', '', [], [ 'access' => 'admin', 'icon' => '...', 'labels' => 'test', ] );

Answer (score -1, accepted):

at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/BackendModules/BackendModuleApi/Index.html you find the step by step guide.

Further I can recommend, to take a look, like other extensions do it. F.e. https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager/

1. In https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager/blob/develop/ext_tables.php the module is registered.
2. In line 18, there is there reference to the Controller and the actions, which are allowed
3. The controller is located in /femanager/ClassessController/ (https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager/blob/develop/Classes/Controller/UserBackendController.php)
4. Further you need also a html template for each action (look at femanager/Resources/Private/Templates/UserBackend/)

Comment: thanks for explanation but i am new here and getting this error    

`The default controller for extension "Transmedial" and plugin "TransmedialMysection" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.`      

**my code is **     

 `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
    'Vendor.transmedial',
    'mysection',
    '',
    '',
    [],
    [
        'access' => 'admin',
        'icon' => '...',
        'labels' => 'test',
    ]
);`